# Node js javascript group json array to the sub arrays and put data in hour interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Hi I have a json data where i have multiple entries recorded with the timestamp. i want to filter the records and make a new sub array that will group all the entries with an hour interval.

like i have the json

```
var arr= [
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 02:02:58", "amount": 7.00 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 02:12:32", "amount": 6.50 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 02:13:11", "amount": 7.25 },
  { "ip":"44.44.44.44", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 02:13:54", "amount": 8.75 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 05:02:45", "amount": 11.00 },
  { "ip":"44.44.44.44", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 06:32:42", "amount": 5.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 06:35:12", "amount": 2.00 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 06:45:01", "amount": 12.00 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 06:59:59", "amount": 11.75 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:01:53", "amount": 1.00 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:02:54", "amount": 4.50 },
  { "ip":"33.33.33.33", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:02:54", "amount": 15.75 },
  { "ip":"66.66.66.66", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:02:54", "amount": 14.25 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:03:15", "amount": 12.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 08:02:22", "amount": 3.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 09:41:50", "amount": 4.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 10:02:54", "amount": 5.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 11:05:35", "amount": 10.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:02:21", "amount": 6.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:02:40", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"44.44.44.44", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:02:55", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:33:34", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:42:24", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:47:44", "amount": 6.25 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 14:02:54", "amount": 4.25 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 14:03:04", "amount": 5.25 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 15:12:55", "amount": 6.25 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 16:02:36", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 16:22:11", "amount": 8.50 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 17:18:19", "amount": 11.25 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 18:19:20", "amount": 9.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 23:59:59", "amount": 9.00 }
]
```

Now i want to output a new array of json with the ips grouped in time interval.

What i have done is this code

```
var arr2 = [];

arr.forEach(function(itm) {
    var now = new Date(itm.timestamp),
        put = arr2;
        
    arr2.forEach(function(itm2) {
        itm2.forEach(function(itm3) {
            var d = new Date(itm3.timestamp);
            if (d.getHours() == now.getHours()) {

                put = itm2;
            }
        });
    });
    put.push(put == arr2 ? [itm] : itm);
});

console.log('arr1', arr2)
```

the code is running fine . but i dont think this is the best approach because this will run many iteration loops and i want to make it cost efficient. can anyone tell me the best possible way or can code for me ?

you can use any npm package you want.

adding fiddle for reference - https://jsfiddle.net/gku24x9m/

Comment: Can you add output to your result.?

Comment: @JustRaman -  added fiddle in the question please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a map with group data by `hours` then convert into a a list.

```js
var arr = [
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 02:02:58", "amount": 7.00 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 02:12:32", "amount": 6.50 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 02:13:11", "amount": 7.25 },
  { "ip":"44.44.44.44", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 02:13:54", "amount": 8.75 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 05:02:45", "amount": 11.00 },
  { "ip":"44.44.44.44", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 06:32:42", "amount": 5.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 06:35:12", "amount": 2.00 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 06:45:01", "amount": 12.00 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 06:59:59", "amount": 11.75 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:01:53", "amount": 1.00 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:02:54", "amount": 4.50 },
  { "ip":"33.33.33.33", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:02:54", "amount": 15.75 },
  { "ip":"66.66.66.66", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:02:54", "amount": 14.25 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:03:15", "amount": 12.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 08:02:22", "amount": 3.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 09:41:50", "amount": 4.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 10:02:54", "amount": 5.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 11:05:35", "amount": 10.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:02:21", "amount": 6.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:02:40", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"44.44.44.44", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:02:55", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:33:34", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:42:24", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:47:44", "amount": 6.25 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 14:02:54", "amount": 4.25 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 14:03:04", "amount": 5.25 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 15:12:55", "amount": 6.25 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 16:02:36", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 16:22:11", "amount": 8.50 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 17:18:19", "amount": 11.25 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 18:19:20", "amount": 9.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 23:59:59", "amount": 9.00 }
]



var resultSet = {};

arr.forEach(function(item) {
    var hour = new Date(item.timestamp).getHours();
    if(resultSet[hour] !== undefined){
      return resultSet[hour].push(item);
    }
    return resultSet[hour] = [item];
});

const resultList = Object.values(resultSet);

console.log(resultList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by hour interval in a single pass by reducing (grouping) `arr` into a map based on each timestamp's hour, then converting the map's values into the desired array.

```js
var arr= [
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 02:02:58", "amount": 7.00 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 02:12:32", "amount": 6.50 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 02:13:11", "amount": 7.25 },
  { "ip":"44.44.44.44", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 02:13:54", "amount": 8.75 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 05:02:45", "amount": 11.00 },
  { "ip":"44.44.44.44", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 06:32:42", "amount": 5.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 06:35:12", "amount": 2.00 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 06:45:01", "amount": 12.00 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 06:59:59", "amount": 11.75 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:01:53", "amount": 1.00 },
  { "ip":"11.11.11.11", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:02:54", "amount": 4.50 },
  { "ip":"33.33.33.33", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:02:54", "amount": 15.75 },
  { "ip":"66.66.66.66", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:02:54", "amount": 14.25 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 07:03:15", "amount": 12.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 08:02:22", "amount": 3.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 09:41:50", "amount": 4.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 10:02:54", "amount": 5.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 11:05:35", "amount": 10.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:02:21", "amount": 6.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:02:40", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"44.44.44.44", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:02:55", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:33:34", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:42:24", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 13:47:44", "amount": 6.25 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 14:02:54", "amount": 4.25 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 14:03:04", "amount": 5.25 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 15:12:55", "amount": 6.25 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 16:02:36", "amount": 8.00 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 16:22:11", "amount": 8.50 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 17:18:19", "amount": 11.25 },
  { "ip":"55.55.55.55", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 18:19:20", "amount": 9.00 },
  { "ip":"22.22.22.22", "timestamp":"3/11/2016 23:59:59", "amount": 9.00 }
]

var arr2= [...arr.reduce((hourLogsMap, log) => {
  const hour = log.timestamp.split(' ')[1].split(':')[0]
  if (hourLogsMap.has(hour)) {
    hourLogsMap.get(hour).push(log)
  } else {
    hourLogsMap.set(hour, [log])
  }
  return hourLogsMap
}, new Map()).values()]

console.log('arr1', arr2)
```